# Почему SQLAlchemy не обновляет объект после повторного его запроса?

Tags: python, flask, orm, sqlalchemy

Есть такой пример:

```
alex = session.query(User).filter_by(name='Alex').first()
# в этот момент соответствующая запись в БД изменяется другим процессом
alex = session.query(User).filter_by(name='Alex').first()
# объект alex не изменится и будет соответствовать первому запросу, т.е. по сути у объекта останутся устаревшие данные, не соответствующие текущему состоянию БД
session.commit()
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться, чем обосновано такое поведение?

Объяснение в доках довольно не понятное:

> Сессия не может полностью предсказать, когда тот же запрос SELECT,
>   выполненный во второй раз, обязательно вернет те же данные, которые у
>   нас уже есть, или это будут новые данные.

Почему бы просто не обновить атрибуты объекта полученными данными из БД, новыми или старыми?
Дальше совсем не ясно:

> So as a best guess, it assumes that within the scope of a transaction,
>   unless it is known that a SQL expression has been emitted to modify a
>   particular row, there’s no need to refresh a row unless explicitly
>   told to do so.

Answer (score 0):

```
# immediately re-load attributes on obj1, obj2
session.refresh(alex)

# expire objects obj1, obj2, attributes will be reloaded
# on the next access:
session.expire(alex)
```

Сегодня столкнулся с такой же проблемой. Ответ, который я представил выше, был найден мной по [ссылке](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19144652) - там же смотрите объяснение, спасибо пользователю [Mark Hildreth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/272520/mark-hildreth)!